# Estimating population mean from sample data – Extrapolate from moving average?

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics

my friend and I had an interesting disagreement about a statistical scenario, and we were wondering if we could get your perspective on it.

There’s a large population of numbers, let’s say 1000. We don’t know any of the numbers at the beginning, but we are given them one at a time at random. We don’t know anything about the shape, variance, or central tendency of the numbers. We know that we are accessing the numbers randomly.

Numbers from the population are revealed one at a time, and after each number is revealed we take the mean of the numbers we've seen. In this case, we notice that the mean starts high and gets lower as more numbers are revealed. Let's say after 20 numbers are revealed, we must guess the mean of the whole poluation.

The debate is how we should guess the population mean. Should we…

•   Use our current sample mean as our estimate, with no adjustment, OR
•   Assume that trends in the numbers continue. If the sample mean descended, on average, while the numbers were revealed to us, we extrapolate that descension will continue.

Phrased another way, given this downward trend is there a 50/50 chance the population mean is above/below our sample mean or is the population mean more likely to be below?

Hopefully that’s clear. Let us know if you need more explanation about the scenario.

Comment: If it is true "we are accessing the numbers randomly," and if that includes supposing the values are *independent,* then the trend is meaningless.